# Making a simple Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

Am trying to do an Ajax call from my local computer using Lampp server, and it keeps giving this error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/AjaxProject/sample.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
>   loadText @ trying.html:27

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Ajak tutorials</title>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="button">Change text</button>
    <p id="text">Let Ajax change this </p>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',loadText);
    function loadText()
    {
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET','sample.txt',true);
        xhr.onload=function(){
            if(this.status==200){
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=this.responseText;
            }else if(this.status==404){
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML="Not found";
            }

        }

        xhr.send();
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you running this javascript, ie what file is it in and are you accessing it from a locally running http server or just opening a file on your hard drive? The error you're getting describes the problem, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy you may also want to try the file in firefox and see if you get the same error.

Comment: am running the javascript from the htdocs folder in Lampp.....that folder contains both my html file which i pasted above and my sample.txt file which i want to load Asynchronously

Comment: if you copy your html file and sample.txt to a folder by themselves and open the html straight from disk does it work? Also please confirm the file permissions of sample.txt as suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

check file and folder permissions. Also, you sometimes need to add the "txt" extension in htaccess on the line of permitted extensions that can be executed by the web browser.

some installations might have this in htaccess, that you might have to modify:

```
      IndexIgnore *.zip *.txt
```

Also, sometimes, if the file navigation is turned off, it would disable the file:/// protocal. check for:

```
        Options -Indexes
```

Also, setting a header might cause the browser to handle the request better, 
 so, right after the xhr.open() line:

```
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
```